# How to show a Progress Indicator before my listview.builder has finished building the listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a huge `ListView` with a lots of data, so it takes a few of seconds before loading it, is there a way to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` or `LinearProgressIndicator`? is there a way to understand the state of the `ListView.builder`?

Below there is the code with what I've tried to do:

```
class _PlantsPageState extends State<PlantsPage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  List<dynamic> _searchResult = [];
  List<dynamic> _plantDetails = [];
  bool _isLoading = false;

  Future getPlantDetails() async {
    final response = await Plants().getPlants();

    setState(() {
      for (dynamic plant in response.data) {
        //print(plant['Name']);
        _plantDetails.add(plant);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getPlantDetails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('plants'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Column(
              children: <Widget>[
        
                Expanded(
                    child:
                        _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                            ? _plantsListView(_searchResult)
                            : _plantsListView(_plantDetails)
                            ),
              ],
            ),

  ListView _plantsListView(_plant) {
    _isLoading=true;
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _plant.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Row(children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(width: 100),
                            Container(
                                width: 250,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      _plant[index]['Name'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                        getCompanies(_plant[index]).toString()),
                                    Text(getClients(_plant[index]).toString()),
                                  ],
                                )),
                            SizedBox(width: 100),
                            Container(
                              width: 150,
                              child: Row(
                                children: isOnline(_plant[index]) +
                                    getTopics(_plant[index]) +
                                    hasAlarm(_plant[index]),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 100),
                            Container(
                                width: 150,
                                child: Visibility(
                                    visible: isVisible(_plant[index]),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Total'),
                                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                                        Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              calculateProd(_plant[index])
                                                  .toString()
                                                  .replaceAll('.', ','),
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            Text(' ' + getUnit(_plant[index]))
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ))),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () => {},
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        thickness: 5,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]));
        });
  }
```

How Could I do it?

Comment: have you tried using `Future.delayed();` ?

Comment: where should I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is simply that you go through your list twice unnecessarily. in your `response.data` you should already have what you need, so you can remove this piece of code

```
 for (dynamic plant in response.data) {
        //print(plant['Name']);
        _plantDetails.add(plant);
      }
```

in order to avoid passing it again as it is a huge object as you said  and you won't need the progress indicator

Answer (score 0):

An excellent approach is to paginate the results of the list. An example can be found in this tutorial. [From Ying Chen, Medium](https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part-5-listview-pagination-scroll-up-to-load-more-ed132f6a06be)

Comment: but My problem is another, I want to show the 'CircularProgressIndicator' before the  'ListView' is loaded

Comment: not once the listview has already been loaded

Answer (score 0):

just add this changes to code it will work
`

```
 class _PlantsPageState extends State<PlantsPage> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  List<dynamic> _searchResult = [];
  List<dynamic> _plantDetails = [];
  bool _isLoading ; // ---------do this here 

  Future getPlantDetails() async {
    final response = await Plants().getPlants();

    setState(() {
      for (dynamic plant in response.data) {
        //print(plant['Name']);
        _plantDetails.add(plant);
        _isLoading = false; // do this false here after getting all data 
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _isLoding = true ;// do this true here 

    getPlantDetails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('plants'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Column(
              children: <Widget>[
        
                Expanded(
                    child:
                        _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                            ? _plantsListView(_searchResult)
                            : _plantsListView(_plantDetails)
                            ),
              ],
            ),

  ListView _plantsListView(_plant) {
    // remove _isLoading from here .....
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _plant.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Row(children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(width: 100),
                            Container(
                                width: 250,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      _plant[index]['Name'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                        getCompanies(_plant[index]).toString()),
                                    Text(getClients(_plant[index]).toString()),
                                  ],
                                )),
                            SizedBox(width: 100),
                            Container(
                              width: 150,
                              child: Row(
                                children: isOnline(_plant[index]) +
                                    getTopics(_plant[index]) +
                                    hasAlarm(_plant[index]),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 100),
                            Container(
                                width: 150,
                                child: Visibility(
                                    visible: isVisible(_plant[index]),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Total'),
                                        SizedBox(height: 5),
                                        Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              calculateProd(_plant[index])
                                                  .toString()
                                                  .replaceAll('.', ','),
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            Text(' ' + getUnit(_plant[index]))
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ))),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onTap: () => {},
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        thickness: 5,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]));
        });
  }
```

`

Comment: my problem is in building the listview not in in the api response, with this code the CircularProgressIndicator only run for a second then  it stop himself but the Listvview isn't built

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using the [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget in Flutter by providing `initialData` and `future` properties.
Find the code snippets below:

```
  Future<String> _loadData() async {
    // Specifies the indicator's duration / delay
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)); 
    return Future<String>.value('Loaded');
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(),
       body: FutureBuilder<String>(
         future: _loadData(),
         initialData: 'Loading',
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
           if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == 'Loading') {
              return _buildIndicator();
           } else {
             return _buildListView();
           }
         },
       ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child:
                      (_searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty)
                          ? _plantsListView(_searchResult)
                          : _plantsListView(_plantDetails)
                          ),
            ],
          );
  }

  Widget _buildIndicator() {
    return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
  }
```

Comment: my problem is in building the listview not in in the api response

Comment: What type of issue did you face while building listview?

Comment: Because my problem is in building the ListView, not in in the api response, with this code the CircularProgressIndicator only run for a second (waiting the api response) then it stop himself but the Listvview isn't built

Comment: Why did you call setState while adding items to the _plantDetails collection inside the getPlantDetails method?

Comment: Because I also implemented a searchMethod